# Installed and set colorscheme but method puts and print not working on ruby

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

Yesterday, I Installed vim and some colorscheme like gruvbox, monokai, molokai.

I set it in `~/.vimrc` and turned on the syntax highlight, everything work well on HTML but in ruby files (`.rb`) it still have colorscheme but few keywords like `puts` and `print` are still in grey color, it looks weird and boring.

That is two syntax I'd using alot during the time I learning. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This depends more on the syntax elements defined/available to ruby and whether or not the colorscheme makes use of them. I will investigate further later

Comment: What system are you using, and which version of Vim? I've noticed when editing a new ruby file that I often have to redraw the screen with ^L to get the syntax highlighting to appear correctly on my work machine, gVim 8.0 on 64 bit Win 7.

Comment: @HieuC hope that answer helps

Answer (score 2):

D.Ben Knoble has given a [terrific explanation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17301/343) of exactly what happens in the default Ruby syntax configuration.

However, I don't care for his two proposed solutions:

1. Complain to the Ruby syntax maintainers,
2. Edit the Ruby syntax file in your local Vim installation, which may then be overwritten when you update Vim.

Vim offers two much simpler solutions:

## 1. Define your own `keyword` syntax items

You can define syntax *keyword* items (`:help :syn-keyword`) for the strings you want to highlight. These will be used in preference to the existing `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod` item because that is a lower-priority `match` item. (See `:help :sy-priority`)

1. From your terminal, start editing a new file inside your `.vim` directory:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.vim/after/syntax
   vim ~/.vim/after/syntax/ruby.vim
   ```
2. Add the following contents:

   ```
   syntax keyword Error puts
   syntax keyword Error print
   ```

   These highlight the literal strings listed with the `Error` highlight group.

   (I picked this group simply because it's likely to show up in a bright colour in most colour schemes. You will probably want to pick a more appropriate group by viewing the output of the `:hi` command.)

## 2. Override the existing syntax item

1. Same as before:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.vim/after/syntax
   vim ~/.vim/after/syntax/ruby.vim
   ```
2. Add the lines:

   ```
   syn match rubyLocalVariableOrMethod "\<[_[:lower:]][_[:alnum:]]*[?!=]\=" contains=NONE display
   highlight link rubyLocalVariableOrMethod Error
   ```

Because the code in the `after/syntax` directory runs *after* Vim's standard syntax files, this overwrites the existing `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod` syntax item replacing it with a copy of it that does not contain the `transparent` argument.

The second line then sets up a link to highlight the item with the existing `Error` highlight colours. (`:help hi-link`).

Which of these solutions you decide to use will depend on your specific requirements.

Comment: Good answer Rich; I don't do much monkey-ing around with syntax highlighting, and would rather leave it to people who know what they're doing (for the moment—it seems high time I learn). Hence my suggestions. I'm glad you were able to provide some alternatives that allow for more customization!

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things going on here that prevent colorization of the word `puts` in ruby files. I examine them (and what led to their discovery) separately.

#### Setup

First, create the temporary file `some.rb`, which `vim` will rightfully detect as ruby code. I gave it the contents

```
puts "stuff"
```

#### Initial thoughts

Next, I ran `vim -u DEFAULTS some.rb`. To my surprise, `puts` wasn't highlighted. Time for further investigation! (To eliminate it being something in the defaults script, I also used `vim -u NONE some.rb` and slowly enabled filetype detection, syntax, &c. I noticed the same results.)

#### Finding the syntax group

I use my plugin [synstax](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax) and the mapping `<Leader><Leader>s` to get the value of the syntax element under the cursor. The [relevant code](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax/blob/6d24f658c6fe21ef6ac2f84c3f91e52d5670ff9f/autoload/synstax.vim#L12-L28) is reproduced in *Notes*.

The highlight group is: `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod`. Don't ask me why, that's just how the syntax file defines it.

#### The highlight

`:verbose highlight rubyLocalVariableOrMethod` gives, unsurprisingly, `cleared`. Alright, I think, the colors are just getting cleared. We can track that down.

In `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/ruby.vim`, we find at line 122:

```
syn match rubyLocalVariableOrMethod "\<[_[:lower:]][_[:alnum:]]*[?!=]\=" contains=NONE display transparent
```

At line 515:

```
hi def link rubyCapitalizedMethod   rubyLocalVariableOrMethod
```

There are the only two occurrences in the entire `$VIMRUNTIME` directory. So no colorscheme even makes use of it.

So it's not getting 'cleared' so much as never being `:highlight`ed. Alright, switch back to `some.rb` and `:highlight link rubyLocalVariableOrMethod Statement`.

...

Hint: it won't work.

The `:verbose highlight ...` idiom gives the expected results: colors, linked to `Statement`. But why isn't it showing up on the screen?

#### Syntax & highlight attributes

Take another look at the definition:

```
syn match rubyLocalVariableOrMethod "\<[_[:lower:]][_[:alnum:]]*[?!=]\=" contains=NONE display transparent
```

We have the standard `syn match <name>`, followed by a pattern to match. Sounds good. `contains=NONE`... a little weird, if you're not familiar, but it seems to indicate things matching this pattern don't contain other syntax groups.

It's easy to miss, being at the end of a longer line, but `display` and `transparent` come next. Hmm, I think, this could be relevant.

`display` simply indicates that no highlighting need be done when the syntax element is off screen; it's a tiny optimization for vim which can reduce it's overall memory consumption (cf. `:help :syn-display`).

`transparent`, on the other hand, is the culprit. *It effectively **disables** colors!* See `:help :syn-transparent` for an explanation.

> This is useful for syntax items that don't need any highlighting but are used only to skip over a part of the text.

#### End result

No matter what highlighting you try to apply to `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod`, it won't show up.

#### Where do I go from here?

File a bug with the syntax maintainers, possibly with a patch that would fix it: you might
- remove `transparent`, or
- add `puts` and other special words to a different group that has highlighting
- something else.

Or, you could monkey-patch your own copy of vim, deleting the `transparent` word and putting special highlighting in your vimrc. You'd need to do this with every update as well though, since your changes are liable to be blown away.

#### *Notes*

The synstax code, as referenced above:

```
function! synstax#UnderCursor() abort
  let l:stack = synstax#Stack(line('.'), col('.'))
  if empty(l:stack)
    return "No syntax highlight groups under cursor"
  endif
  let l:names = synstax#Attributes(l:stack, 'name')
  return l:names
endfunction

function! synstax#Stack(line, col) abort
  return synstack(a:line, a:col)
endfunction

function! synstax#Attributes(stack, attr) abort
  let l:attr_func = printf('synIDattr(v:val, "%s")', a:attr)
  return map(a:stack, l:attr_func)
endfunction
```